# A topology on algebras that coincides with a certain idea of density

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, category-theory, universal-algebra

In the category of Hausdorff spaces and continuous maps, the inclusion $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ is epic, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and I think in a way the notion of epic arrow is a good translation of what density means.

For instance in the category of rings and ring morphisms, the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ is again epic, and this shows that in a sense $\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Q}$: $\mathbb{Q}$ is (as a ring) "entirely determined" by $\mathbb{Z}$. Obviously this density isn't the one in the sense of the usual topology on these rings.

However I was wondering if this can be captured in a certain topology on $\mathbb{Q}$, and more generally I have the following question :

Given a category of structured sets (for instance a category of algebras in the sense of universal algebra- in particular varieties for instance) and structure-preserving maps, can the structured sets always be furnished with a topology that makes epimorphisms in said category the morphisms whose image is dense (wrt to said topology) ?

If you have an answer in a specific case, I'll take it as well, I don't necessarily need an answer as general as the question. For instance if you have an answer for the category of rings, or for varieties, or for algebras, etc. I'll be glad to hear it.

EDIT : As has been noted in a comment, the trivial topology would work. As this obviously isn't satisfactory, I'll think about other things that such a topology would have to verify. But still, you can try and guess what I would expect from it, until I come up with natural things to prevent trivial examples

Comment: You could go for the trivial topology on $\mathbb{Q}$. But that's obviously not what you're looking for. So you have to be more conrete: What properties should the inclusion map have? What topology should be on $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes you're right I need to add some specifications. I think the topology should make the algebra a topological algebra, i.e. it should make the basic operations continuous (this still doesn't exclude the trivial topology though, unfortunately). I'll think about it, thanks for noticing that

Comment: Here is a possible way to make the question more precise. Call a subset $S$ of a ring $R$ "ring-dense" if every ring morphism from $R$ to any other ring is determined by its restriction to $S$. The question is whether there is a natural topology on $R$ such that the dense subsets (in the topological sense) are exactly the "ring-dense" subsets of $R$. I don't know the answer in general, but for $\mathbb Q$ I think the unique topology satisfying this requirement is the trivial one since every subset of $\mathbb Q$ would need to be dense.

Comment: The "determined by its restriction to $S$" part is exactly the requirement that the inclusion map be epic, when $S$ is a subring. About the specific example of $\mathbb{Q}$ you may be right, but we may not want that every ring-dense subset be dense, but simply that every ring-dense subring be dense. I don't know if that would change much... but we need to remember that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not any ring (initial object in the category of fields of characteristic $0$, but also it's the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}$ which is the initial object in the category of rings)

Comment: Just an idea: What if we call a subset $U \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ open if and only if it contains all but finitely many elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ or if it is the empty set?

This is a topology: $\emptyset, \mathbb{Q}$ are open by definition. An arbitrary union still contains all but finitely many integers and a finite intersection too.

The subspacetopology of $\mathbb{Z}$ is the cofinite topology of $\mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, every non-empty open set intersects $\mathbb{Z}$ by definition.

This shows that there are at least non-trivial examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $V$ be a variety. If $A, B\in V$ and $A$ is a subalgebra of $B$, and $b\in B$, then $A$ **dominates** $b$ relative to $V$ if
any two homomorphisms that agree on $A$ also agree on $b$. 
The set of elements of $B$ dominated by $A$ is the
**dominion** of $A$ in $B$ relative to $V$. The map that assigns a subset its dominion is a closure operator on $B$. A homomorphism into $B$ is an epimorphism iff its image is dense with respect to this closure operator.

Dominion is not a topological closure operator: closed sets are subalgebras, so the union of two closed sets is usually not closed. Also, the empty subset need not be closed.
However, it may be that what is wanted it just a link between epimorphisms and denseness, in which case I would suggest Isbell's paper:

J. Isbell. Epimorphisms and dominions. In Proceedings of the Conference on Categorical
Algebra: La Jolla 1965 , pages 232246. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 1966.

For a more recent description of this closure operator, you might look at the 2016 preprint

Epic substructures and primitive positive functions by Miguel Campercholi, which you can download from

https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.03139

Comment: Thats very interesting, I'll look it up ! Though I was mostly interested in a topological denseness, so I'll wait and see if other answers go more in that direction